# Matlab - modify class attributes

Tags: matlab, class, attributes

i'm trying to simulate a car's position with Matlab.
So far I have created a class representing the car with public attributes position (obj.position), speed (obj.vIst) and delta (obj.delat). Delta represents the time steps.
When I let my car drive I want to change it's position by adding the actual speed. Unfortunately it isn't working...

The code

```
fprintf(' \n Position: %4.0f',  obj.position );
obj.position = obj.position + obj.vIst*obj.delta;
fprintf(' \n Position: %4.0f',  obj.position );
```

creates the following output:

```
Position: 1000
Position:
```

What am I doing wrong? Has this anything to do with a handle or value class? I'm pretty sure my question is stupid but im just starting to work with Matlab so i'm needing some help here...

Thanks very much in advance.

The class definition:

```
classdef myCar < handle
    %UNTITLED Summary of this class goes here
    %   Detailed explanation goes here

properties
    id;
    typ;
    startzeit;
    vStart;
    posStart;

    position;
    vIst;
    vSoll;
    vMax;
    laenge;
    aktiv = false;
    vMaxStrecke;

    POI;
    vPOI;
    POIaktiv = false;

    bremswegZumPOI;
    bremsverzoegerung = 0.8;

    aGeg = [];
    vGeg = [];
    delta;

    zeitLinie = [];
    vIstLinie = [];
    posLinie= [];
    vSollLinie = [];
end

methods
    function drive(obj, time)
            fprintf(' \n in fahre: %4.0f',  obj.position );
            obj.position = obj.position + obj.vIst*obj.delta;
            fprintf(' \n in fahre: %4.0f',  obj.position );

            obj.zeitLinie = [obj.zeitLinie, time];
            obj.vIstLinie = [obj.vIstLinie, obj.vIst];
    end
end
end
```

The Method drive is called from another script managing several cars.

Comment: Can you include the classdef, methods etc. in the question text?

Comment: How do you initialize your object properties? And is that the entire `classdef`? Is there a constructor?

Comment: In your example, the result of the second `fprintf` shows nothing (unlike the 1000 from the previous statement).  I can get the same result if one of the `obj.vIst` or `obj.delta` is an empty matrix.  Are you sure that both have been initialized to something valid?

Comment: I found the error - thanks for asking for the constructor. I forgot to set the obj.delta attribut though I passed it through via a parameter.